# Why am i get 0 while execute the query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql, while executing this query it updates the column value as 0:

```
UPDATE table_name set column_name='some_value ' AND same_column_name='different_value'
```

I am not getting any error while using AND in UPDATE Statement in my PHP program.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

It's interpreting your expression as a Boolean then saving it as an int.

`column_name='some_value ' AND same_column_name='different_value'`  is false, probably then converted to int with value of zero.

More MySQL idiocy.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL syntax is wrong, the correct syntax should be separated by comma

Your statement is actually update Column_name to the AND result of 'some_value' and same_column_name='different_value

```
UPDATE table_name set column_name='some_value ',  same_column_name='different_value'
```

Comment: or UPDATE table_name set column_name='some_value ' WHERE same_column_name='different_value', its hard to tell :)

Comment: This seems to make more sense, :)